# Codeigniter model is not loading in controller

Tags: codeigniter

Using this site_model in the controller below gives me a 500 internal error. I can't even add the model to my index as well. I can use this model in another controller, bot not the index.

Is there something wrong with my model class?

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model{


    function getAll(){
        $q = $this->db->get('ci_test');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        return $data;
        }

    }



    function getAllCup(){
        $q = $this->db->get('cup');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        return $data;
        }
    }

    function getOrderCup(){
        session_start();

        $order = $_SESSION['order'];



        $this->db->select('product_id','name','description','price');


        foreach($order as $product):
            $this->db->where('product_id', $product['product_id']);
        endforeach;

        $q = $this->db->('cup');



        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        return $data;
        }

    }




}
```

/////

```
 class Checkout extends CI_Controller{


    function index()
    {



        $data['main_content'] = "checkout";
        $this->load->view("includes/template",$data);
    }


    function review()
    {

            $this->load->model('site_model');
            /*echo json_encode($this->site_model->getOrderCupcakes());*/

            echo "sfsfdsf";
    }


}
```

Comment: it's there, scroll down. They attached

Comment: @Adam you must have to see my answer i hope you identify your problem

Answer (score 0):

look at the changes which i have made at `// problem solved`

```
class Checkout extends CI_Controller{


function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = "checkout";
    $this->load->view("includes/template",$data);
}


function review()
{
   //$this->load->model('site_model');
   // problem sloved
   $this->load->model('site_model');
   $getOrderCupcakes = $this->site_model->getOrderCupcakes();       
   print_r(json_encode($getOrderCupcakes));
   // problem solved
   /*echo json_encode($this->site_model->getOrderCupcakes());*/
   //echo "sfsfdsf";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things.

First, in your model, `$q = $this->db->('cup');` is not valid. You'll need to access a valid method like `$this->db->get('cup')` (the actual method depends on what exactly you're trying to do).

Also, although it's currently commented out, you have a method in your model named `getOrderCup()`, but you're trying to access a method in your model (from your controller) named `getOrderCupcakes()`. You'll need to change one or the other.